# gVim access environment variable with special characters

Tags: windows, vim, portability

PortableApps automatically add [environment variables](http://portableapps.com/manuals/PortableApps.comLauncher/ref/envsub.html) when using their apps.  However, while using [gVimPortable](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/gvim_portable) to access a variable with a special character in the name, I get errors.

For example:  While executing

```
:echo $PortableApps\.comDocuments
```

or

```
:echo $PortableApps.comDocuments
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
E15: Invalid expression: \.comDocuments
```

and

```
E121: Undefined variable: comDocuments
E15: Invalid expression: $PortableApps.comDocuments
```

I get similar problems when I do a

```
:echo $PAL:Drive
```

The PortableApps environment variables all seems to be there.  I did a:

```
:echo $<C-D>
```

And they are listed.

How do I access these variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Vim, environment variables can only contain alphabets, digits and underscore. From [`:h expand-env`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#expand-env):

```
…  Any non-id character (not a letter, digit or '_') may
follow the environment variable name. That character and what follows is
appended to the value of the environment variable.  Examples: 
   :set term=$TERM.new
   :set path=/usr/$INCLUDE,$HOME/include,.
```

So, with an expression like `set something=$PortableApps.comDocuments`, Vim sees only `$PortableApps` as the environment variable - `.comDocuments` is a string to appended to it. With `echo $PortableApps.comDocuments`, `.` is the [string concatenation operator](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-.), so Vim tries to take the value of 
`$PortableApps` and the variable `comDocuments` and join them. With `echo $PortableApps\.comDocuments`, it sees the environment varible `$PortableApps`, followed by something it can't make sense of: `\.comDocuments`.

If you have access to Vim's Python or Perl interfaces, you can use them instead. For example, after starting Vim with:

```
env foo.bar=blah vim
```

Both of the following gave the output `blah`:

```
:perl VIM::Msg($ENV{"foo.bar"})
:python import os; print os.environ['foo.bar']
```

Within Python, for example, you could assign the environment variable to a Vim variable:

```
:python vim.vars['foobar'] = os.environ['foo.bar']
```

Then, you could use `foobar` like any other Vim variable:

```
:echo foobar
blah
```

Of course, being on Windows, you would have to install Python or Perl to use this.

Comment: It says `Any non-id character may follow the environment variable name.`  Doesn't this mean that environment variables can have special characters?  Thanks @muru!

Comment: @watchtheblur the full paragraph in the help makes it  clearer. I have updated the answer to include it.

Comment: That gives me a better idea of environment variable expansion! Thanks @muru!

Comment: @watchtheblur you're welcome. If you're interested in using Vim better, do check out the sister site [vi.se].